# Optimize binary multivariate polynomial multiplication

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time, binary, polynomials, multiplication

You have a few variables that can only assume the values 0 or 1 and you use those to form two polynomials. Is there a way to multiply the two polynomials that is faster than O(n²) where n is the number of terms in the polynomial?

What I could come up with:

- As the variables are binary, they all follow the equation X²=X
- You can represent any polynomial of this kind with an array of $2^n$ values, where n is the number of variables, where each index represents the variables multiplied and the value at the index position represents the quantity multiplied.

Example: for a polynomial with 3 variables, the array indexes will be as follows:
0 - _
1 - a
2 - b
3 - a * b
4 - c
5 - a * c
6 - b * c
7 - a * b * c

And the polynomial 1+3a-2b+bc could be represented as [1, 3, -2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

- to add two polynomials in this representation you just have to add the arrays
- the value of the multiplication of two terms can be calculated multiplying their values and the index can be found by applying OR in their indexes. Example: array A and array B represents two distinct binary polynomials and K is the result of the multiplication.
  `A[i] * B[j]` -> `K[i | j] = A[i] * B[j]`

So, is there a faster way than looping and distributing each term?

Comment: Your representation requires an array of size $2^n$. It can be much more than the actual number of terms in the polynomial.

Comment: @Dmitry you are correct, thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo in the question. And while it can be much more than the actual polynomial, I can't think of a better representation than that for making the calculations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Polynomial_multiplication, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Polynomial_multiplication

Comment: Are your polynomials sparse or dense? How many variables are involved?

Comment: The answer could also depend on the representation that you use. For example, if you multiply $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ by $y_1 + \cdots + y_n$ and you represent polynomials as sums of terms, then you cannot do better than $\Theta(n^2)$, since the resulting polynomial has $n^2$ terms. In fact, it could be worse if each monomial has high degree — your upper bound of $O(n^2)$ doesn't necessarily hold, depending on your model of computation.

Comment: Most of the coefficients are not zero, so I'd guess it's dense. The variables are usually around 32